# “undefined” shows up in console when button clicked

Tags: javascript

```
class Elemento
{
  constructor (numerito)
  {
  this.numero = document.getElementById(numerito).innerText
  this.boton = document.getElementById(numerito)

  }
  escribir()
  {
    console.log(this.numero)
  }
}
numeroUno = new Elemento("1")
numeroUno.boton.addEventListener("click", numeroUno.escribir)
```

I'm trying to show in console *numerito* value when button is clicked but instead it shows "undefined".

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. This is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; focus on the specific issue at hand, and write a title that reflects it.

Comment: Can you, please, add more code? Where is this located in your HTML? Make sure to run this code once the HTML is rendered by placing this script at the bottom of the page for example.

Comment: It would be better to write down your code sample in english instead of your native language, it will be easier to read for most of the community members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suspect this is a `this` binding issue - when the event handler `numeroUno.escribir` is called by the browser after the user clicks the button, it has "lost the context" of the `numeroUno` object.

One solution this is to use the `bind` method to fix the `this` reference of the method, no matter how it is called:

```
class Elemento
{
  constructor (numerito)
  {
    this.numero = document.getElementById(numerito).innerText
    this.boton = document.getElementById(numerito)
    this.escribir = this.escribir.bind(this) // add this line
  }

  escribir()
  {
    console.log(this.numero)
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but you shouldn't overwrite the method like that. Instead you should do that in the event handler, `addEventListener("click", numeroUno.escribir.bind(numeroUno))`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That is exactly what you **should not do**. That way you cannot remove the event listener at any time of the lifecycle. Overwriting the method with a bound copy of itself is exactly the right thing to do.

Comment: @connexo Ah, fair enough. It's been too long since I've used `addEventListener` directly XD

Comment: thank you so much for your response, it solved the issue. Im going to read documentation for bind method to understand how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You are not utilising the value that you pass to the constructor, try this:

```
class Elemento
{
  constructor (numerito)
  {
  this.numero = numerito  // See here, use the numerito passed to the constructor function
  this.boton = document.getElementById(numerito)

  }
  escribir()
  {
    console.log(this.numero)
  }
}
numeroUno = new Elemento("1")
numeroUno.boton.addEventListener("click", numeroUno.escribir)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be fixed by ***explicitly binding the function*** in the class to ***this***.

**Binding syntax is:**

> function_name = this.function_name.bind(this)

**Here is the working solution:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>demo</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button id="1">Numerito</button>
    </div>
    <script>
       class Elemento {
           constructor (numerito) {
               this.numero = document.getElementById(numerito).innerText
               this.boton = document.getElementById(numerito)
           }
           escribir() {
               console.log("numero = " + this.numero)
           }

           // JavaScript expects an explicit binding of each function in the class
           //
           // Binding syntax is:  
           //
           // function_name = this.function_name.bind(this)

           escribir = this.escribir.bind(this)
        }
        numeroUno = new Elemento("1")
        numeroUno.boton.addEventListener("click", numeroUno.escribir)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks but the line escribir = this.escribir.bind(this) worked only into constructor